# Copy column rows to be the first rows in column

Tags: mysql, table

I have two database tables named `vegan_ar_sheet1` (old) and `vegan_en_sheet1` (new).

Now I want to copy the column `name` and all of its contents from the `vegan_ar_sheet1` table to the `vegan_en_sheet1` table into the field named `name_ar`. I created the column in the new table using the following  MySQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE new_table ADD name_ar TEXT ;
```

Then I copied the contents of the column using this MySQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO vegan_en_sheet1 (name_ar) SELECT name FROM vegan_ar_sheet1;
```

I have a problem now, which is that the column contents added were added to the end of table and not at the beginning. This is not what I intended.

How could I copy the contents of the `name_ar` column into the other table and add the contents as the first column in the table and not at the end of the table, because I found out that other columns have null values after adding the fourth column contents.

```
CREATE TABLE vegan_ar_sheet1 (
    name         varchar(78) DEFAULT '', 
    price         varchar(7) DEFAULT '', 
    description  varchar(76) DEFAULT '', 
    image       varchar(102) DEFAULT '', 
    department  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
    id               int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE vegan_en_sheet1 ( 
    name         varchar(69) DEFAULT '', 
    price       decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL, 
    description  varchar(65) DEFAULT '', 
    image       varchar(102) DEFAULT '', 
    name_ar      varchar(78) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Perhaps you wanted a multi-column UPDATE.

Comment: Hello Rick, thanks for clarifying this, what is the syntax of update command should i use ? , thanks again in advance

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  And explain which column you need to copy from one table to the other.

Comment: Hi Rick, here are the output for "show create table" mysql command :
CREATE TABLE `vegan_ar_sheet1` (`name` varchar(78) DEFAULT '', `price` varchar(7) DEFAULT '', `description` varchar(76) DEFAULT '', `image` varchar(102) DEFAULT '', `department` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: CREATE TABLE `vegan_en_sheet1` (
 `name` varchar(69) DEFAULT '',
 `price` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` varchar(65) DEFAULT '',
 `image` varchar(102) DEFAULT '',
 `name_ar` varchar(78) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


Now i need to copy all rows inside "name" field from "vegan_ar_sheet1" table into "name_ar" field inside 

"vegan_en_sheet1" table, so that the rows will be added inside "name_ar" field starting from first row till end of  copied rows, thanks in advance for your kind cooperation & help

Comment: Any help will be appreciated, my knowledge in mysql ends in basics, not advanced procedures, & many thanks Rick for trying to help me

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy `name_ar` from `vegan_ar_sheet1` to the other table??  Do something like this:

```
-- Add the column:
ALTER TABLE vegan_en_sheet1 ADD COLUMN name_ar varchar(78) DEFAULT NULL;
-- Copy the values over:
UPDATE vegan_en_sheet1,
       vegan_ar_sheet1
    SET vegan_en_sheet1.name_ar = vegan_ar_sheet1.name
    WHERE vegan_en_sheet1.??? = vegan_ar_sheet1.???
```

Notes

- `ADD COLUMN`, not just `ADD.
- Use the same datatype (`VARCHAR` instead of `TEXT`)
- The `UPDATE` has a problem -- the `WHERE` needs to somehow line up the rows so that they match.  Maybe `image` would be good for matching?  But only if all of them are different.
- As for "line up" -- A database table has no concept of 'order'.  If you need to distinguish one row from another, you must have a column (or combination of columns) that uniquely identifies each row.  This is normally the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Hello Rick
Thanks again for your help, i did all sql statement but dont used where clause, i found that rows in column name_ar updated, but all rows have repetitive value which is the first row in old table

Comment: You _must_ provide a way of mapping the rows of one table to the other.  I cannot tell from your limited information if there is any such way.  I left the `WHERE` clause as incomplete to emphasize the need for this relationship.